# Most Efficient way to render a large amount of simple shapes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, skia

I'm implementing a particle system renderer in my Flutter application.

Currently I'm using a CustomPainter which renders each particle as a rectangle using `canvas.drawRect()`. But I need to draw thousands of such rectangles and doing and while being very simple shapes, flutter seems to have difficulties handling it as the performance drops t less than 30 fps from the steadily 60 I am targetting.

Since the shapes I need to render are just quads with no textures, all of the same size differing just by their color, I was wondering if using a versatile tool such as a custom painter was the right choice for this application.

I know a bit of OpenGL and I know that for small meshes (made up of a small number of vertices) such as a rectangle it's better to load them into a single buffer and draw them in one single call, or even better to draw them using as instances as they are identical except for the color.

I tried using OpenGL via this package https://github.com/mogol/opengl_texture_widget_example as it said that it worked both for Android and iOS but I couldn't get it to work as it's a very old package.

Is `canvas.drawRect()` the best way to draw a large number of simple shapes in flutter, or are there faster ways to do so either in flutter itself or using third party packages?

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, [canvas.drawVertices()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawVertices.html) is the fastest way to draw. If you are able to create vertices with the [vertices.raw()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Vertices/Vertices.raw.html), this can increase the drawing performance. `drawVertices()` basically draws triangles so you can draw every rectangle by drawing two triangles. I have a mobile app which draws about 260 000 (510x510) rectangles 60 fps. The absolute fastest way to draw is by using [fragment shaders](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/advanced/shaders) but this can be hard and impractical to implement.